# when no checkboxes are selected show a message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of store names with check boxes attached.
I have another list of taxonomies that belong to these stores.
When I click on a store it only shows me the taxonomies that have the same value.

I used this script to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".store_checkbox").change(function () {
    $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();

});
```

Now I want to show a message under my taxonomies **if no boxes are selected**

How might do this?

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if($('.store_checkbox').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show(); // any one is checked
} else {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // none is checked
    }  
});
```

but it just hides the message regardless if there are checked or unchecked boxes

I also tried this :

```
$(function () {

if($('.store_checkbox').not(':checked')){
alert("no check boxes");
}
});
```

**Updated script all together**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".store_checkbox").change(function () {
    $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
if(!$('.store_checkbox').is(':checked')){
$("#hidden_taxon_message").show(); // any one is checked
 } else {
$("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // none is checked
}
});
```

**Latest Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".store_checkbox").change(function () {
    $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();

checkIfChecked();

});

$('.store_checkbox').on('change', function () {
checkIfChecked();
});

function checkIfChecked() {
if ($('.store_checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show(); // none are checked
} else {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // something is selected
}
}
```

this is what my js file looks like. the message doesnt seem **TO HIDE**.
am I putting it in right?

**Mark Up**

```
  <h3>Stores Offered In</h3>
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
    <% for store in Store.all %>
        <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[store_ids][]", store.id, 
@idea.stores.include?(store), :class => "store_checkbox" %> <%= store.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <br />

  <hr />

  <h3>Taxonomies Offered In</h3>
  <% for store in Store.all %>
     <% if store.has_taxonomies? %>
     <div store_id='<%= store.id %>'> 
        <h4><%= store.name %></h4>
          <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
            <% for taxonomy in store.taxonomies %>
                <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[taxonomy_ids][]",   
taxonomy.id, @idea.taxonomies.include?(taxonomy) %> <%= taxonomy.name %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
    <div id="hidden_taxon_message">
        no checkboxes are selected            
    </div>
```

Comment: Based on your question, you're logic seems backwards.  If you want to show a message when 0 are selected, wouldn't you do == 0 instead of > 0, or switch your show() / hide()?

Comment: It looks like you are only testing whether to display the message once (upon document ready). It seems that you'll want to perform that test every time a checkbox is changed, right? Possible to include your HTML as well?

Comment: does my updated question eliminate the upon document ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your check to the change event of the input boxes, like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
        $("#warning").show(); // any one is checked
    } else {
        $("#warning").hide(); // none is checked
    }
});
```

So that when a new checkbox is selected the code will run.

See this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/JxSXY/

**EDIT**

For nothing selected you need to check on document load as well as on change, see the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    checkIfChecked();
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    checkIfChecked();
});

function checkIfChecked() {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
        $("#warning").show(); // none are checked
    } else {
        $("#warning").hide(); // something is selected
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/JxSXY/2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is showing a message when something IS clicked i am trying to do he opposite

Comment: the example works great! I am just having a hard time putting it all together with my other script:     `$(".store_checkbox").change(function () {
        $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();`

Comment: Does this work for you? I updated my checkboxes to have classes and gave my warning element the same id: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/JxSXY/3/

Comment: I updated my question to show you what I have and see why it might not be working

Comment: Preferably the generated mark up, I can't do much with the mark up you've posted unfortunately.

Comment: that is ok I think I figured it out. Thank you for your help

Comment: Not a problem, if this helped you can you please mark it as the correct answer? If not, post your solution and mark it as the correct one. Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.store_checkbox` is a class assigned to all your checkboxes, your logic 
needs to look something like this:

```
if($('.store_checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show(); // any one is checked
} else {
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide(); // none is checked
};
```

Alternatively, you could use a little different syntax, more like your second example. Interestingly, [the opposite of jQuery's .is() method is not .not(), it is !.is()](http://ajpiano.com/the-opposite-of-jquerys-is-method-is-not-not-it-is-is/):

```
if(!$('.store_checkbox').is(':checked')){
    alert("no check boxes");
}
```

To put it all together, you can do something like this (thanks to @gibbeirsh's edit for the jsfiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.store_checkbox').click(function() {
        msgconfig();
    });
    msgconfig();
});
function msgconfig(){
    if ($('.store_checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
    }else{
        $("#hidden_taxon_message").hide();
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfBw8/1/)**

Comment: Whoops. I had an extra bracket in my code, which may have broken your code entirely. I just edited to fix that problem.

Comment: the second code works nicely on page load but not after I deselect when I am on the page